# SharePoint 2010 - Create mosaic with user's uploaded pictures

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mosaic

this is my first time actually submitting a question here so let me know if you need more information.

I am using SharePoint 2010 and we literally just migrated from SharePoint 2007 so I don't have much experience in 2010 yet. I need to create a mosaic similar to [this one](http://h-d-mosaic.com/) including the search functionality.

What would be the best way to implement this? I've been considering Silverlight, but I'm not very experienced with it. Thoughts? Suggestions?

I'm not looking for a full solution from start to finish, but more of general ideas on how you would approach this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since there'll be a search, you need to first create some columns to search by.

Then in order to generate a mosaic, you'll need an algorithm to create such thing by the results everytime and bind the generated mosaic. I've found some silverlight code (that in my opinion not very successful but may be enough for your reqs) [here](http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/23/photo-mosaic-generator---fun-adventures-with-silverlight)

Then, you'll have to create a silverlight project and the rest can be easily found in so to put the silverlight object in a web part.

Sure, this is the general outline, you'll need to drilldown.